# GWT ClassCastException

Tags: java, gwt

I am running the gwt web app in tomcat. I am getting the below failure in OnFailure() while doing RPC.

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ctc.wstx.stax.WstxInputFactory cannot be cast to javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
```

Can anyone let me know why this happens. Thank you

Comment: You must show snippets of your code that may be causing this, as well as a stack trace of the exception thrown, otherwise it won't be possible to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you are casting an object to **javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory** which is failing. Can you please upload your code snippet, so we can know what is happening